70's or 80's Science Fiction novel that misused the word "ecology"
The book I am thinking of was written sometime in the 1970's or 1980's, and was about a bunch of people colonizing a harsh and unforgiving world. The world had giant spiders and buffalo-slug-like creatures. The (male) author's name MAY have had an L in it.  In the sequel there was an incest-adjacent storyline involving the children of the original colonists. The relationship dynamics in the first book were pretty weird too. Other than that, the chief thing I remember about was that it overused and misused the word ecology. The author used the word ecology all over the place when ecosystem or environment would have been a better fit for what he was trying to say.

Different wildlife, but Legacy of Heorot by Larry Niven et. al.? Sequel focused on the children of the first generation.

No, I don't recall the grendels at all. It sounds interesting! But not quite what I am looking for.

David Gerrold abuses the term ecology in the way you describe in his Chtorr books, but they are set on a devasted Earth not a distant planet.

This isn't the book I'm looking for, BUT the reason I'm looking for the book is to quote some misuses of the term. I'm doing a science-writing exercise of defining a technical term by starting with examples of what the term is not. So I'll check this book out! Thanks

Sounds a bit like Murray Leinster's The Forgotten Planet. There's another version called Mad Planet, which tells a different story, but I don't know if they are sequels as such.

Any chance this is the 1975 book Midworld by Alan Dean Foster? The sequel was written much much later and was forgettable, at least I forgot everything about it, but I do think there were children of a lost colony in it.

@bob1 Not the book I'm looking for, but it is interesting! In a kind of "how would I modify this for modern audiences" sort of way.

@OrganicMarble that one isn't it either. The book I am trying to recall was a lot less empathetic in tone, much more "this planet is out to kill us" rather than keeping a planet safe and untrammeled (from the wikipedia description). I sure am getting some interesting science fiction recommendations this way though! Thanks

@Shawn are you sure the wildlife is different? I really strongly remember slug-like grazers and everything else seems similar enough according to the Wikipedia summary

@jani I have text searched The Legacy of Heorot and the sequel Beowulf's Children and the word "slug" occurs only as a term for a bullet. If you're sure the grazers are referred to as "slugs" then these are not the books you remember.

Can you remember exactly how the grazers were described? e.g. were they "slugs the size of buffalos" or if not what simile was used to describe them? I ask because this seems a pretty distinctive feature of the books and might trigger someone's memory.

@JohnRennie they weren’t described as slugs per se, more like giant grazer that had like a mantle or something like it (it was electric blue and perhaps bioluminescent?). I don’t know that anyone ever used the word slug but my teenage self came away with the impression of slugs or snails or something like that. I do remember the female lead of the second book and her brother were like doing science on them or something? And running with lots of descriptions of long legs, etc.

Are you sure their usage of “ecology” was not fairly normal in that period, somewhat comparable to “geology of the Rockies”? (It is obviously unfair to ask you to provide quotes!) Wikipedia says “Ecology…is the natural science of the relationships among living organisms…and their physical environment”, but en.Wiktionary also offers “3: The totality or pattern of relationships of components of a system with their environment and…each other”. I remember first meeting “ecology” as referring to stuff like marking out a square metre of ground and trying work out how all the plants were interacting.

Yeah, I checked the OED today, and that use of ecology is listed there

@PJTraill does answering yes or no to your question help identify the book?

It would not help me, I fear!

@Shawn you were right! Make your comment an answer and I’ll give you the credit. I finally got a copy of the book. It doesn’t misuse ecology in the way I was thinking but it is a later edition so editing may have happened.
